# convert vector3 to transform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I get the error

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Vector3' to 'UnityEngine.Transform'"

What is the most effective way to convert a Vector3 to Transform?

example of use:

```
        Vector3 spawningpos = getSpawnPos();
        Instantiate(myPrefab, spawningpos);
```

Comment: Why don't you declare spawningpos as a `Vector3` since you use it as a simple position ?

Comment: Transform is a component which holds up all "transformation" related values. It's almost impossible to convert simple Vector3 into structure containing rotation, position, scale etc.

Comment: "spawningpos.position = new Vector3(Random.Ran..." but this is not the right way to do stuff. EDIT: see the answer below why and how :)

Comment: why not instantiate with a Vector3 with: public static Object Instantiate(Object original, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation); and as for the rotation use Quaternion.identity since it doesn't seem to matter for you?

Comment: @Alox check my answer, I suggest just that :)

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre I just realized that, oupsie lol, sorry :P

Comment: Also Diggs if my answer has helped feel free to accept it :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your issue is explained very well by the error you're receiving, lets have a look

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Vector3' to 'UnityEngine.Transform'"

So where are you trying to set a `Transform`'s value to a Vector3?

```
private Transform spawningpos;
```

`spawningpos` is a Transform

```
spawningpos = new Vector3(Random.Range(-spawningAria, spawningAria) + transform.position.x, 2f, Random.Range(-spawningAria, spawningAria) + transform.position.z);
```

But here you are clearly setting its value to a `Vector3`

```
Instantiate(insects[Random.Range(0, insects.Length)], spawningpos);
```

On this line you then instantiate the object - using the `Transform` as input. As you will find [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html), the overload you are using for the method is actually asking for the **parent's** Transform, try this instead

```
private Vector3 spawningpos;
```

Followed by, as before

```
spawningpos = new Vector3(Random.Range(-spawningAria, spawningAria) + transform.position.x, 2f, Random.Range(-spawningAria, spawningAria) + transform.position.z);
```

And finally

```
Instantiate(insects[Random.Range(0, insects.Length)], spawningpos, Quaternion.identity);
```

This code will call the correct overload of the `Instantiate` method, setting the object's rotation is mandatory when passing a `Vector3`

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly convert a Vector3 object to a Transform. I found a simple way to do it.

- First create a spawnPosition - an empty gameobject in your scene.
- Set transform position to (0,0,0)
- Add random values to the position.
- Use transform of the spawnPosition.

Try my following demo code,

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CubeSpawner : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField] GameObject cube;
    [SerializeField] Transform spawnTransform;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start() {
        InvokeRepeating("SpawnCubes", 2, 0.5f);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update(){
    }

    void SpawnCubes() {
        spawnTransform.position = new Vector3 (Random.Range (0f, 10f), 18f, 0f);
        GameObject cube1 =Instantiate(cube, spawnTransform) as GameObject;
    }
}
```